# Function attached to window.addEventListener gets called automatically on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

displayMessage1() function gets called automatically on page load with values `{"message":null,"messageType":"ready_anchor"}`

Instead of it getting called only when the event gets fired. How do I invoke this function only when the event is fired.

```
<head>
    <script>
                function displayMessage1(event) {
                    $('#messageText').val(event.data);
                }

                if (window.addEventListener) {
                    window.addEventListener("message",displayMessage1, false);
                } else {
                    window.attachEvent("onmessage", displayMessage1);
                }
        </script>
    </head>
```

Comment: [No, it doesn't](https://jsfiddle.net/7zcjuxL6/). Whatever's sending that message is in code you haven't shown.

Comment: Side note: Why have your own `addEventListener`/`attachEvent` code when you're already using jQuery, which handles it for you? `$(window).on("message", function(e) { /* use e.originalEvent.data here */});`